# Is it possible to configure Safari to automatically open an app for a given file type?

Tags: macos, safari, calendar.app

Specifically, I would like to make it open Calendar automatically when downloading `.ics` files, instead of having to download them, then click on the file to have Calendar open it.

Please don't explain to me how to configure the default app to open a file on MacOS, this is *not* the question I'm asking - this is specific to Safari on MacOS (I know how to do to this on Firefox, so please *don't* explain to me that one either)

Answer (score -1):

Open Safari Settings (`⌘` `,`) → General → ✅ Open "safe" files after downloading

[image: Open "safe" files after]